# Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore release notes

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, changelog

Does anybody know if there's a release notes for EntityFramework Core package? In my case, before upgrading to 2.19.70 version of the package, I would like to know which improvements or feature have been brought to the package.

The [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore) site has not references to it. Also tried the Oracle Community forum but had no luck.

Before upgrading production apps I would appreciate a changelog file or some information about the upgrade. Am I the only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to get the changelog of the new Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 2.19.70. Just **upgrade the package** using nuget and you will be prompted to the Readme.txt of the new package.

A website with this readme.txt hosted would be appreciated by Oracle but anyway it was a nice surprise to discover it once installed. I don't share the content of the readme.txt in this answer since I don't want to violate any copyright.